# Perspective transform with WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, 3d, 2d

WPF allows to specify linear affine transform on graphical objects. With this you can do translation, rotation, scaling, skewing, or a combination of that. You can specify a 2x3 matrix.

What I want to do is a perspective transform in 2D space, which requires a 3x3 matrix, and is known from Photoshop or GIMP, where you can drag all 4 corners of an image independently.

I tried to use the 3D features of WPF, set up a `Viewport3D`, an `OrthographicCamera` and placed the (2D) objects onto the xy-plane.

But I'm wondering if there is no easier way to accomplish the perspective transform in WPF?

I'm asking also because I'd like to do the perspective transform on text: in 2D I can use a `TextBlock`, in 3D it gets more compliacted, I'd have to create a `Brush` out of a `Geometry` out of a `FormattedText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can [read here](https://groups.google.com/group/wpf-disciples/browse_thread/thread/6672e591b23a7589) there are some 3rd party libraries that implement Silverlight's PlaneProjection for WPF.

Otherwise you will be forced to code it yourself. (Perhaps Microsoft will add the PlaneProjection in a future version of .NET)

Comment: Thank you for the link, I found The Planerator useful (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greg_schechter/archive/2007/10/26/enter-the-planerator-dead-simple-3d-in-wpf-with-a-stupid-name.aspx). Another article I encountered does exactly what I need: http://www.charlespetzold.com/blog/2007/08/250638.html

Comment: Also [C#.Net - Perspective Image Transform](https://www.ok.unsode.com/post/2015/07/04/csharp-net-perspective-image-transform) which describes a projective transform with bilinear interpolation. Else I suspect the transformation matrix can be created [with Direct3D](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb323340(v%3Dvs.85))